# create a PHP function that works for simple arrays and nested arrays

Tags: php, arrays, jagged-arrays

I am trying to create a function that works on both simple arrays and nested arrays.  So far, the function looks like this:

```
function fnPrepareDataForBrowser($values)
  {
    $values = array_map('htmlspecialchars', $values);   
    return $values;
  }
```

It works fine for simple arrays - for example:

```
Array
(
    [Item ID] => 25469
    [Item Desc] => spiral nails, 1"
    [Standard Item] => yes
    [Entry UOM] => lb
)
```

But it fails with the message "Warning: htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given..." for nested arrays - for example:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [Item ID] => 25469
        [Item Description] => spiral nails, 1"
        [Standard Item] => yes
        [Entry UOM] => lb
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [Item ID] => 25470
        [Item Description] => finishing screws, 2.5"
        [Standard Item] => no
        [Entry UOM] => lb
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [Item ID] => 25576
        [Item Description] => paint brush, 3"
        [Standard Item] => no
        [Entry UOM] => each
    )
)
```

What modifications should be made to the function so it works for both simple arrays and nested arrays?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function fnPrepareDataForBrowser(& $values)
{
    return is_array($values) ? 
           array_map('fnPrepareDataForBrowser', $values) : 
           htmlspecialchars($values);   

}

$array = fnPrepareDataForBrowser( $your_array );
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<?php
    /**
     * Applies callback function recursively to every element of the given array.
     *
     * If the array contains inner arrays or objects, the callback is also applied
     * to these.
     *
     * Caution: If $arrayOfObject is an object, only public members are processed.
     *
     * @param callback     $func
     * @param array|object $array
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public static function array_map_recursive($func, $arrayOrObject)
    {
            $array = is_array($arrayOrObject) ? $arrayOrObject : get_object_vars($arrayOrObject);
            foreach ($array as $key => $val) {
                    $array[$key] = is_array($val) || is_object($val)
                            ? self::array_map_recursive($func, $val)
                            : call_user_func($func, $val);
            }
            return $array;
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this array_map_recursive function instead. I stole it from the manual.

```
function array_map_recursive($callback, $array) {
    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        if (is_array($array[$key])) {
            $array[$key] = array_map_recursive($callback, $array[$key]);
        }
        else {
            $array[$key] = call_user_func($callback, $array[$key]);
        }
    }
    return $array;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this suit your needs?

```
<?php

function fnPrepareDataForBrowser(&$values)
{
    $result = array();

    foreach ( $values as $k => $v )
    {
        if ( is_array( $v ) ) {

            array_push( $result, array_map('htmlspecialchars', $v) );
        }
    }

    return $result;
}


$tst = array(
array (
        'Item ID' => 25469,
        'Item Description' => "spiral nails & 1",
        'Standard Item' => 'yes&',
        'Entry UOM' => 'lb>'
    ),

array (
        'Item ID' => 25470,
        'Item Description' => "finishing screws & 2.5",
        'Standard Item' => 'no&',
        'Entry UOM' => 'lb<'
    ),

array (
        'Item ID' => 25576,
        'Item Description' => "paint brush & 3",
        'Standard Item' => 'no&',
        'Entry UOM' => 'each&'
    )
);

$result = fnPrepareDataForBrowser($tst);

print_r( $result );
```

Produces these results

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Item ID] => 25469
            [Item Description] => spiral nails &amp; 1
            [Standard Item] => yes&amp;
            [Entry UOM] => lb&gt;
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Item ID] => 25470
            [Item Description] => finishing screws &amp; 2.5
            [Standard Item] => no&amp;
            [Entry UOM] => lb&lt;
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [Item ID] => 25576
            [Item Description] => paint brush &amp; 3
            [Standard Item] => no&amp;
            [Entry UOM] => each&amp;
        )

)
```